# Problem with client-server application on java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, deadlock

Good day, I'm a beginner developer and I'm trying to write a client-server application. My application should work like this, it checks if the file has been modified and if so, it is sent to the server, the question is how to organize this?
I did it through the socket, but if I get a deadlock, I will be grateful for any comments, I attach the code further

Server

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        Socket client;
        BufferedInputStream clientInputStream;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;
        StringBuilder fileName;
        byte[] mass;
        {
            fileName = new StringBuilder("this.txt"); // give name for file
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);  // open server in 5000 port
            mass = new byte[1]; // create new buffer array
            client = serverSocket.accept(); // waiting connect
            clientInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream()); // to accept byte's array
            byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();    // to write byte array in file
        }

        {
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream;

            int bytesRead;
            // FIXME: 02.07.2022 первый файл
            do {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(mass, 0, mass.length);  // write by one byte in array
                bytesRead = clientInputStream.read(mass, 0, mass.length);
            } while (bytesRead != -1);
            FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(fileName.toString()); // stream for file write
            bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(writer);
            bufferedOutputStream.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), 0, byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray().length); // write file
            System.out.println("first f");
            bufferedOutputStream.flush();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));

            bufferedWriter.write("success");    // if file send success then write string in socket and send to client
        }

        {
            serverSocket.close();
            client.close();
            clientInputStream.close();
            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        }
        }
    }
```

And Client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

    private final static String serverIP = "192.168.0.47"; // server ip address
    private final static int serverPort = 5000; // server port address
    private final static String fileOutput = "first.txt"; // first file to send
    private final static String fileOutput1 = "second.txt"; // second file to send

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        Socket client = new Socket(serverIP,serverPort); // make new connect with my server
        BufferedInputStream inputFile = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileOutput)); // convert file to array bytes
        // FIXME: 02.07.2022 first file
        BufferedOutputStream clientSocketOutputWriter = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()); // this is the stream to send to the socket
        byte[] massByte  = inputFile.readAllBytes(); // this going on convert file to array bytes
        clientSocketOutputWriter.write(massByte,0, massByte.length); // send array bytes to server
        System.out.println("first file send");
        //----------------if i remove this two string, program begin work successfully but i can't send several file because this beging deadlock
//        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
//        String s = bufferedReader.readLine();
        //----------------


        System.out.println("the end");
        clientSocketOutputWriter.close();
        client.close();
        inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `ByteArrayOutputStream` is pointless here. Just write directly to the file. Unclear what you're really asking.

Comment: after the file has been sent to the server, the server must send a string to the client that everything was delivered successfully, but the client starts waiting indefinitely for the string, although the server sent it. Server line 38 40 and Client line 23 24

Comment: The server does not leave the loop (lines 29-32), because no EOF is sent by the client. You could do that by closing the `clientSocketOutputWriter` directly after the first file is sent, but this breaks the subsequent code as it also closes the socket.
My suggestion is: Have the client send the length of the file as the first 4 bytes or so and after that send the contents of the file. The server then knows how many bytes to expect and can leave the loop once all bytes have arrived.

Answer (score 0):

If the TCP connection isn't closed,The variable `bytesRead` will never be -1 because the code `clientInputStream.read(mass, 0, mass.length);` keeps executing   and waiting for data.If you want to send a file,you should send its length first then you can call `byte[] data=clientInputStream.readNBytes(its length)`,or put its data into a object and use `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` to send the object.
The variable `bytesRead` isn't -1 means the server cannot leave the loop,so the server cannot put the data which it has just received into a file.Just use `writer.write(mass);` instead of `byteArrayOutputStream.write(mass, 0, mass.length);`,write the data to the file directly then stop running the program can solve the problem too.